# I want to convert a piece of violin I heard on youtube into a waveform (amplitude versus time or frequency)

Tags: sound

I want to convert a piece of violin I heard on youtube into a waveform (amplitude versus time or frequency). How to do this using Mathematica, please? I suspect it may have something to do with processing a MIDI file. That is all  I know.

Comment: Well, you also know which piece you want to convert, which would be a key piece of information to share with us. If it comes from YouTube, it will be a video file, not a MIDI file. There are also many websites that allow you to extract the audio from a YouTube video and save it as an MP3 file, which is a compressed waveform (Google "audio from youtube").

Comment: Thanks. So can I use Mathematica commands to turn an MP3 file into a waveform? I want to be able to plot this waveform amplitude versus frequency or amplitude versus time..

Comment: Yes. You can use Import and import the .mp3 file into Mathematica. See ["MP3"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MP3.html) in the documentation, in particular the "Data representation" choices under "Import elements". Note that a waveform, as I understand it, is a representation of amplitude vs. *time*. Amplitude vs. frequency is a spectrogram.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will try.